# Any less impolite alternatives for the too-informal interjection “Hell”?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, offensive-language, register, exclamations

Consider the passage:

> Mathematicians are pretty comfortable with treating spaces without any embedding. A surface can *just* exist—no need for a volume for it to hover in. It does so with all its properties attached: curvature, roughness, holes, etc. ***Hell*, even a measly point** can boast of its existence without any assist from “3Dness”.

It’s as if even the simple point were shaking its defiant fist in the face of “3Dness” and proclaiming that the the point’s existence is not subject to “approval” by “3Dness” for the point to actually exist.

However, the interjection *Hell!* seems out of place to me in the register needed for formal writing, so I don't wish to use it. The [OED says of this interjection](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/85636) that its usage ranges from “informal” to “impolite”:

> Expressing annoyance, anger, or surprise. Also with intensifying adjective, as ***bloody hell***, ***fucking hell***, etc.
>
> <sup>**The register of usage ranges from informal to impolite.**</sup>

The earliest and latest citations provided for this usage in the OED are these two:

> - 1888    Frederic Thomas Elworthy · *The West Somerset word-book* at *Oaths*   
>   With some individuals ‘Hell! bloody hell!’ serve to eke out most sentences.
> - [...]
> - 2005    Steve Amick  · *The Lake, The River & The Other Lake* xxxii. 131
>      Hell, he’d power-rodded the guy’s main line at least a dozen times and barely charged him the standard price.

I don’t risk coming off sounding informal at best or impolite at worst, so
is there an alternative way of saying what I’m trying to say here that still carries that same “mood” as my original wording without actually using the word *hell*?  I don’t wish to be rude.

Comment: You could leave it out. "Even a ..."

Comment: The mood comes from the informal and unexpected terminology. Preserving the mood would tend to also preserve the qualities that make your discarded term "slang".

Comment: @Lawrence "As a matter of fact"...just isn't right is it

Comment: It's an interjection. Just about any one - or none - would do :) . "As a matter of fact" works, but if you have a good proofreader, be prepared for them to delete the 'empty' phrase.

Comment: Dropping it, thnx.

Comment: @lineage Your English is quite good but you still might be interested in our sister size for [ell.se]. I've taken the liberty to spruce up your question with a research citation and so that it reads better in English. You said that *hell* is “a slang” but that’s not true; it’s also not grammatical to most speakers to use *slang* as a count noun as you have here when it’s normally only a mass-noun. You might use it attributively and say it’s “a slang expression”, but you cannot ever just say “a slang” as though others “slangs” existed. Finally, slang is rather more than merely informal speech.

Comment: Heck, see if any of these work: https://www.thesaurus.com/browse/hell

Comment: And what has the rapper 3Dness got to do with anything?

Comment: @tchrist...quite a heavy edit...I am hopping its still about the same thing I was originally asking. Anyways, I am trusting you with the english since I hardly know much grammar.

Answer (score 1):

Heck

- a (mild) euphemism for hell

[onelook](https://onelook.com/?w=heck&ls=a)

- euphemistic alteration of hell, by 1865.

(Etymology online (linked from above))

Comment: There are a whole bunch of euphemisms for various uses of _hell_. [This discussion of the topic](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/aue/thehell.html) is one that wound up getting linked with [the Chomskybot](http://rubberducky.org/cgi-bin/chomsky.pl).

Answer (score 0):

In formal writing, do not use such informal expressions (hell, measly, boast) at all.  For example:

> ...curvature, roughness, holes, etc. Indeed, even a point can exist without any assist from “3Dness”.